# How to draw graph inside swing with GraphStream actually?

Tags: java, swing, graphstream

I am trying to implement drawing of [tutorial graph inside swing](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation_1.1/#integrating-the-viewer-in-your-gui), but failing.

The code is follows:

package tests.graphstream;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import org.graphstream.graph.Graph;
import org.graphstream.graph.implementations.SingleGraph;
import org.graphstream.ui.swingViewer.View;
import org.graphstream.ui.swingViewer.Viewer;

public class Tutorial1_01
{
    private static Graph graph = new SingleGraph("Tutorial 1");

    public static class MyFrame extends JFrame
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8394236698316485656L;

        //private Graph graph = new MultiGraph("embedded");
        //private Viewer viewer = new Viewer(graph, Viewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_ANOTHER_THREAD);
        private Viewer viewer = new Viewer(graph, Viewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_SWING_THREAD);
        private View view = viewer.addDefaultView(false);

        public MyFrame() {
             setLayout(new BorderLayout());
             add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
             setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
                frame.setSize(320, 240);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                graph.addNode("A");
                graph.addNode("B");
                graph.addNode("C");
                graph.addEdge("AB", "A", "B");
                graph.addEdge("BC", "B", "C");
                graph.addEdge("CA", "C", "A");

                graph.addAttribute("ui.quality");
                graph.addAttribute("ui.antialias");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And it draws this:

[image]

If drag nodes, it turns to:

[image]

How to get results, close to `graph.display()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a side effect due to the fact that nodes do not have `x` and `y` coordinates by default.

To prevent this you should whether :

- activate the `autolayout` on your `viewer` object with `viewer.enableAutoLayout();`
- or specify by yourself some `x`and `y` attributes for each node.

#### With Autolayout

```
// ...
public MyFrame() {
     setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     // Activate autolayout here : 
     viewer.enableAutoLayout();
}
// ...
```

#### With nodes attributes

```
// In main() ...
Node a = graph.addNode("A");
a.addAttribute("xy", 0, 0);
Node b = graph.addNode("B");
b.addAttribute("xy", 10, 0);
Node c = graph.addNode("C");
c.addAttribute("xy", 10, 10);
// ...
```